# Trying to output data with a signal event handler is not working

Tags: perl, signals

I am trying to get some debug output from a script I am working on. For some reason the code below will not output anything:

```
$SIG{'HUP'} = \&dump_state;

sub dump_state {        
    print "dumping state: \n\n";
    debug(Dumper($state));  
}
```

I have tried this with INT and TERM signals as well, but I get no output. What could cause that to happen? I'm at a loss.

I also forgot to mention that "debug()" is a small sub in the app that simply prints to STDERR with some color coding. It is known to work everywhere else in the script.

Comment: Replace `debug` with `print STDERR` to eliminate that being a problem.  You get no output whatsoever, not even "dumping state"?  It's possible `$state` is empty, though even that should dump something.

Comment: Stupid question: are you sending a SIGHUP to the program?

Comment: The program you provided does not suffer from the problem you attribute to it.

Comment: How did you ascertain that debug does not output anything, meaning how did you make sure it was even run?

Comment: I ended up debugging my code in a differetn way since debugging the cause of my debug issue was a waste of time.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the fact that the script uses threads (the only plausible explanation I could think of), but I managed to debug my real issue without this, so if anyone wants to figure it out as an exercise for themselves; be my guest. Thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply tried to use a wrong signal name.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch16_19.htm

Catching CTRL-C is signal INT not HUP.

This code works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $SIG{'INT'} = \&dump_state;

my $i=0;
while(1){
    $i++;
    sleep(5);
}

sub dump_state {        
    print "dumping state: $i\n\n";

}
./hup_test.pl
dumping state: 1

dumping state: 2

dumping state: 3

dumping state: 4

dumping state: 5

Killed
```